Fejer-Riesz Theorem
Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1\}$ and $\mathbb{T}=\{z : |z|=1\}$.
Fejer-Riesz Theorem: If $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $f(z) \geq 0$ whenever $|z|=1$. Then there exists a polynomial $A$ that does not vanish on $\mathbb{D}$ and $f(z)=|A(z)|^2$ for all $z \in \mathbb{T}$.
Is there any relation between $A(0)$ and $f(0)$? More precisely, can we choose a polynomial $A$ such that $|A(0)|=|f(0)|$?
I have looked into the proof of Fejer-Riesz theorem but in vain.
